# English meaning of bon jouez ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, traduction

I would like about the English meaning  of   " Bon Jouez", it  is usually used in french language.

Comment: doesn't exist. Closest: "bon joueur" (fair player) or "Bon, jouez !" (ok, play !).

Comment: Both words exist in French but putting them together like this is meaningless. Are you sure about the spelling? Did you hear it or read it? What is the context?

Comment: You could also be confusing this with "Bien joué!", which could mean "Well played!", "Well done!" or even "Good game!"

Comment: @Gilles  Honestly I hear it in the street or some times in some  french films. I know that verb " Jouer " means play, but I dont undertsand what does such expression refer to , when we use it, and is  it a positive or a negative  expression ??

Comment: @Nizar If you have a video/audio sample, let us know, it is probably a misunderstanding/mistake. Hearing it in the street is not always a sign of correctness like the infamous "omelette du fromage". As the previous comments suggest it, there are already many interpretations, so please add details.

Comment: If you're hearing it a lot, maybe that's *[bonjour](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bonjour#French)*, which means “hello” (and has nothing to do with *jouer* meaning play, but is derived from *jour* meaning day — literally “good day”).

Comment: Bon is good, jouez is the imperative; So it has no meaning. It's like saying "good let's play" in English. I think Papa Poule's right, you may have heard "bien joué!"